# How do I find the most common value in more than one column?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, counting, google-sheets-query, google-query-language

When given multiple columns or rows, is there a formula that would return the most common value in the range? Example:

[image]

The formula would return Bird in the example above given columns A and B because Bird shows up 4 times, more than any other value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX(QUERY({A:A; B:B}, 
 "select Col1,count(Col1) 
  group by Col1 
  order by count(Col1) desc"), 2, 1)
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Awesome! Thank you!

One last question: is there a way to omit certain values with this? So that it would ignore part of the data? For example: tell it to ignore bird in the example above.

Comment: sure: `=INDEX(QUERY({A:A; B:B}, 
 "select Col1,count(Col1) where not lower(Col1) = 'bird'
  group by Col1 
  order by count(Col1) desc"), 2, 1)`